# I can't get this puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

A friend sent me this. He said it's all connected. What is the word?  I can't get this.

[image]

Accessible:

```
AFTER THE MATTER OF LIFE
AN URN IN CASA IRE
AN FAN IN PIN ON GON
IT WHAT IT
```

Hint

> Connected. Four different words perhaps?

Hint 2

> Each line has one word connected to all the words or phrases within the line

Hint 3

> The title is also a clue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The first line's word is FACT as in "After the fact" "Fact of the matter" "Matter of fact" "Fact of life"

> The second line's word is SAT as in "Satan" "Saturn" "Satin" "Cassata" "Satire"

> The third line's word is ION as in "anion" "fanion" "onion" "pinion"

> The fourth line's word is IS as in "It is what it is"

So the answer is:

> SAT IS FACT ION ... as in "I can't get no satisfaction"

Comment: FINALLY!!   Amazing solve @kristinalustig

Comment: Honestly I was really stuck on the third one, and then I saw that you'd edited in a hint as I was working on it, and that gave it to me straight away. :) Good puzzle!