# What country is he talking about?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

My friend sent me another of these word connection puzzle. He asked: "What country am I talking about?" He also said that more than one country is a possibility.

[image]

This is linked to "I Can't Get This Puzzle"

[I can't get this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120948/i-cant-get-this-puzzle)

Comment: Based off the answer's solve path, would it be possible to provide a text version of this puzzle? That will make it accessible to screen readers, search engines, and people behind firewalls.

Comment: I will do so soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Partial solution**? since I have identified only one possible country.

Each

> set of four words can have a single letter added to each to make new words, thus:
>  A: **A**ID LE**A**D **A**LONE **A**MEN
>  E: FAR**E** PAR**E** ON**E** PAN**E** | I: FA**I**R PA**I**R **I**ON PA**I**N | T: FAR**T** PAR**T** **T**ON PAN**T**
>  B: **B**AN **B**AY **B**ASS **B**AIL | M: **M**AN **M**AY **M**ASS **M**AIL | P: **P**AN **P**AY **P**ASS **P**AIL (arguably also S)
>  L: P**L**AY **L**ATE **L**AND **L**EAST

One way

> of picking letters gives us AIML, or if reordered MALI. (Reordering the rows seems to be in keeping with RogerA's previous puzzle, referenced here.)

Allegedly

> "more than one country is a possibility". If we don't mind using one letter twice we can also get MALTA, but that seems a bit of a stretch. I don't see any others that use single letters (BALI isn't a country...). Some rows can have longer strings of letters -- e.g., **BR**AN **BR**AY **BR**ASS **BR**AIL (though that last word is pretty obscure); maybe by these means we can make another country, but I haven't so far seen how.